# dismiss modal ViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, segue, modalviewcontroller

I've got a series of nested navigation controllers (because I want the nav bar at the top and I can't get that bar to look correct without using the nav controller).

So basically it looks like this:
-NavigationController-VC1-->(Modal)--NavigationController-VC2-->(modal)...etc

When I'm at the summary ViewController, the final one - I want a button to take the user back to the very root ViewController. How can I do this?

I've tried the popToRootViewControllerAnimated but that doesn't work as I've got a series of navigation controllers (better solution??)

Thanks!

**Edit**

Navigation now:

Navigation Controller --> VC1 --(modal)-->VC2 --(modal)-->VC3... and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say whether your using storyboards or not but if you are try looking into unwind segues.
[What are Unwind segues for and how do you use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-do-you-use-them)

Using an unwind segue should get you back to where you need to be in the hierarchy.

Comment: Sorry, yeah - I'm using storyboards

Comment: You should be able to use the unwind segue feature to get back to anywhere in your hierarchy then.

Comment: I used your approach and it worked very well. I also added a prepareForSegue method to do the save code ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`popToRootViewController:Animated` will only go back to `[0]` of your navigation controller's array of view controllers. So in other words, the root of the first navigation controller will always be VC1, and the root of your second navigation controller will always go to VC2. You should reconsider the structure of your app, because you shouldn't have one navigation controller push to another - it doesn't make sense. Here's what you can do:

`Navigation Controller -> VC1 -> (push segue) -> VC2 -> (push segue) -> VC3`

This way `popToRootViewController:Animated` will go back to VC1.

The only reason I would use more than one navigation controller is if I had some sort of a table with options such as:

```
---
A     Navigation Controller -> VCA1 -> (push segue) -> VCA2 -> (push segue) -> VCA3
---
B     Navigation Controller -> VCB1 -> (push segue) -> VCB2 -> (push segue) -> VCB3
---
C     Navigation Controller -> VCC1 -> (push segue) -> VCC2 -> (push segue) -> VCC3
---
```

Even in this case, the root view controller will always be VCA1, VCB1, or VCC1.

Hope this helps.

It would also help if you post what you are trying to accomplish so we can better understand your question.

Comment: The reason I did this was because the top bar where I had the navigation button was too big If I added an empty prompt, but too small If I didn't. The NavigationController made it perfectly big. I'll try to restructure my app to make it more organized ;) The concept here is sort of like a wizard, adding a new item and adding things to that item along the way. It'll be used for work stuff

Comment: @Erik, oh okay cool. Remember that you can subclass elements to make them look like the way you want them to if you don't want to deal with the extra complexity of the navigation controller. Also you mentioned that its a wizard and that you'll be "adding" prompts, etc. In my opinion all the scenarios should be loaded already and shouldn't be dynamically generated along the way.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks!;) - I'll get some sleep now and continue tomorrow, getting late here

Comment: I tried popToRootViewController:Animated now, but nothing is happening. I think the code is being called as an NSLog after it does fire, but it doesn't dismiss anything. Any ideas? @Carpetfizz

Comment: @Erik, if something happens and there is no error that means you are most probably AT the root view controller.

Comment: I don't understand that, I'm at like number 6 in a series of ViewControllers being modally displayed one after another. Shall I post a screenshot of the ViewController layout?? @Carpetfizz

Comment: I solved the problem using pidge's answer, though I would like to solve the problem with the popToRootViewController:animated. Here's a screenshot of the ViewControllers: http://imgur.com/y2A1GaM     @Carpetfizz

Answer (score 0):

By Writing the First Line you get the Indexes of all View Controllers and from second Line You will reach up to your Destination.

NSArray *array = [self.navigationController viewControllers];

[self.navigationController popToViewController:[array objectAtIndex:2] animated:YES];

Comment: I tried this now but absolutely nothing is happening :/ - did a NSLog after popToViewController and it does log, but it doesn't pop to the viewcontroller. Any ideas why? See my updated question for how the navigation looks now

Answer (score 0):

If you are use same navigation controller to all view controller than this line works fine for you.

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

but in your case you are presenting model view controller.for this case you need to dismiss first model view controller before presenting other one.

Comment: I could use that approach, but then the user wouldn't be able to go backwards in the "wizard"